# Slow VBA when target sheet is in layout view

Tags: excel, vba

**The Background**

I use Excel 2007 in Windows 10. Let say something about the script beforehand: I'm running the script from a worksheet named "calculation" affecting some cells in the worksheet "printlayout". It runs every time some cells in "calculation" are changed. "calculation" is in **normal view**, while "printlayout" is in **layout view**. the modified cells are reset each time the script run, then filled with some strings, then it is applied a text format such as some words become bold (and it is set also the global font stye, the borders, the text wrap).

**The Problem**

1.1) If you open the workbook and the active sheet is "calculation", then the script runs in matter of milliseconds.

1.2) If you change worksheet and go even only one time to see the "printlayout", and then you trigger the script again, it runs REALLY slow, taking seconds to end *(no matter in which worksheet you are: you can change back to "calculation" again but this doesn't affect the result)*.

1.3.1) If you close the file, open it again and the active sheet is "printlayout", then the script runs again in milliseconds (go to point 1.1)

1.3.2) If you instead open the file and the active sheet is "printlayout", then go to point 1.2

1.4) the problem doesn't present itself if I change the view of "printlayout" to normal, but I didn't find any way to do this within the script...

**The Code Sample**

This is the onchange event (in the code of worksheet "calculation"):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' attivazione macro "Grassettare" quando certe celle vengono cambiate
    If Sheets("calculation").Range("activatemacro").Value = "yes" Then
        Dim KeyCells As Range
        Set KeyCells = Sheets("calculation").Range("A2:E80")
        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
            Call Grassettare
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the structure of the code I'm using:

```vb
Sub Grassettare()

' try to speed up the process...
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
    .Calculation = xlManual
End With
Sheets("printlayout").DisplayPageBreaks = False

' code, code, code... some loops,
' not a lot of cells to be looped by the way (about 50)
' end of my code...

Sheets("printlayout").DisplayPageBreaks = True
With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

**More in-depth analysis**

For the ones who asked about the code I omitted in the previous *code sample* section, here it goes! Be aware: it is a bit long. For better understanding I'll try to explain what it does: in "**calculation**" worksheet: the cell range *Z1:AF50* contains a header which represent a property (values from 1 to 7); under that, there are columns where are stored the row indexes which correspond to the names in column "A" that have the aforesaid same property in column "C". There's another column, the "B" one, which may contains the string "*". I create a string containing every name of "A" separated by " - " (e.g. "name1 - name5 - name6") which share the same property in column "C". I put this strings into subsequent cells in "**printlayout**" worksheet. Afterward, I bold the names which have the "*" property in column "B" (e.g. if name5 has property "*" then I get "name1 - **name5** - name6").

At the end of the script you can see that the cells I just updated are also copied below. I think I may copy the entire range to reduce a bit of overhead, instead of copying every cell every step. But this is not the problem.

Have a look:

```vb
' definizioni
Dim valoriColonna As Range
Dim valoriRiga As Range
Dim colonna As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim rig As Integer
Dim length As Integer
Dim temp As String
Dim toBold As String
Dim AtoBold() As String
Dim lista As String
Dim Alista() As String
Dim grassetto As String
Dim Agrassetto() As String
Dim da As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim keepformat(0 To 2) As Variant
Dim cellaFinituraLucida As Integer
Dim cellaFinituraSuede As Integer

' assegnazione
Set valoriColonna = Sheets("calculation").Range("Z1:AF1") ' sono le fascie
Set valoriRiga = Sheets("calculation").Range("Z2:AF" & Sheets("calculation").Range("AS3").Value) ' lista indici riga del colore secondo fascia
cellaFinituraLucida = 8 ' numero riga inizio finitura lucida nei LISTINI
cellaFinituraSuede = 18 ' numero riga inizio finitura lucida nei LISTINI
' assegnazione stile
keepformat(0) = "Calibri" ' Name = nome del font
keepformat(1) = False ' Bold = grassetto (o no)
keepformat(2) = True ' WrapText = testo a capo

cellaFinituraLucida = cellaFinituraLucida - 1
cellaFinituraSuede = cellaFinituraSuede - 1

For col = 1 To valoriColonna.Columns.Count
    grassetto = ""
    lista = ""
    toBold = ""
    length = 0
    For rig = 1 To valoriRiga.Rows.Count
        If IsNumeric(valoriRiga.Cells(rig, col).Value) Then
            colonna = valoriRiga.Cells(rig, col).Value
            If Sheets("calculation").Range("B" & (colonna + 1)).Value = "*" Then
                toBold = toBold & "1" & ","
            Else
                toBold = toBold & "0" & ","
            End If
            temp = Sheets("calculation").Range("A" & (colonna + 1)).Value
            length = length + Len(temp)
            grassetto = grassetto & length & "," ' contiene lunghezze parole divise da virgola
            lista = lista & temp & "," ' contiene parole divise da virgola
            ' Debug.Print "c." & colonna & " lista=" & temp & " grassetto=" & grassetto
        End If
    Next
    ' -----
    Agrassetto = Split(grassetto, ",")
    ReDim Preserve Agrassetto(UBound(Agrassetto) - 1) ' rimosso ultimo elemento
    Alista = Split(lista, ",")
    ReDim Preserve Alista(UBound(Alista) - 1) ' rimosso ultimo elemento
    AtoBold = Split(toBold, ",")
    ReDim Preserve AtoBold(UBound(AtoBold) - 1) ' rimosso ultimo elemento
    ' -----
    ' Debug.Print Join(AtoBold)
    lista = Join(Alista, " - ")
    ' preparo le celle della finitura suede
    With Sheets("printlayout").Range("A" & (cellaFinituraSuede + col))
        .Clear
        .Font.Name = keepformat(0)
        .Font.Bold = keepformat(1)
        .WrapText = keepformat(2)
    End With
    ' preparo le celle della finitura lucida
    With Sheets("printlayout").Range("A" & (cellaFinituraLucida + col))
        .Clear
        .Font.Name = keepformat(0)
        .Font.Bold = keepformat(1)
        .WrapText = keepformat(2)
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Value = lista
    End With
    ' primo elemento
    If AtoBold(0) = "1" Then
        da = 1
        a = Val(Agrassetto(0))
        With Sheets("printlayout").Range("A" & (cellaFinituraLucida + col)).Characters(da, a).Font
            .Bold = True
        End With
    Else
        da = 1
        a = Val(Agrassetto(0))
        With Sheets("printlayout").Range("A" & (cellaFinituraLucida + col)).Characters(da, a).Font
            .Bold = False
        End With
    End If
    ' successivi elementi
    For rig = 1 To UBound(Agrassetto)
        If AtoBold(rig) = "1" Then
            da = Val(Agrassetto(rig - 1)) + 1 + 3 * rig ' origine (start)
            a = Val(Agrassetto(rig)) - Val(Agrassetto(rig - 1)) ' lunghezza parola
            With Sheets("printlayout").Range("A" & (cellaFinituraLucida + col)).Characters(da, a).Font
                .Bold = True
            End With
        Else
            da = Val(Agrassetto(rig - 1)) + 1 + 3 * rig
            a = Val(Agrassetto(rig)) - Val(Agrassetto(rig - 1))
            With Sheets("printlayout").Range("A" & (cellaFinituraLucida + col)).Characters(da, a).Font
                .Bold = False
            End With
        End If
    Next
    ' copio le celle della finitura lucida in quelle della suede
    Sheets("printlayout").Range("A" & (cellaFinituraLucida + col)) _
    .Copy (Sheets("printlayout").Range("A" & (cellaFinituraSuede + col)))
Next
```

**The Question**

Is this a known bug? Is it preventable? how so? Thank you, let me know if somebody has any idea!

Comment: _" ...then filled with some strings"_: this is a potential cause for triggering `Worksheet_Change()` again and again in an endless loop -> put `Application.EnableEvents = False` right before `Call Grassettare` and `Application.EnableEvents = True` right after

Comment: Not related to your question,  but `Range(Target.Address))` is exactly equivalent to `Target`

Comment: Also not related to your  Q, the correct way to reference the sheet a event is triggered on is to use `Me`.  So `Sheets("calculation").Range(...` should be `Me.Range(...`

Comment: @HTH noop, that can't be the problem since the change event is triggered only in "calculation" sheet, not in the target "printlayout". By the way, I added your 2 lines of code and, as expected, didn't solve the problem... thank you by the way!

Comment: that's why I said "potential"

Comment: @chrisneilsen thank you, I'll edit my code to be more "correct". I'm relatively new to VBA, and I follow what doc.microsoft tell me to do most of the times, seems even they are not so knowledgeable on their work ;)

Comment: IMHO `doc.microsoft` examples do an ok job of demonstrating the Propery or Method being described ( although are often far from complete), but do a _terrible_ job of demonstrating good practice

Comment: We'll need to see more of `Grassettare()` to offer any real advice  here

Comment: @chrisneilsen I just added the missing code, it could be a bit confusing at first, but vba is not my native code language and I have to be... ehm... creative to get things done